# flask 404 eror: is this related to crsf token?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and following the [flask mega tutorial part 5](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins).

The version I have is running on AWS EC2 at http://34.220.113.126 now.

The rest worked fine - if you log in by using Id='susan' and pawwword='cat', you can see the content of the index page. But when I tried to register a new user, it will return an error like this:

```
http://34.220.113.126/%22%20method=%22post?csrf_token=IjQzYmU3ZmRmMDc1ZGZkMmI5MTA3NjcxODk4Zjc3NzJlY2QzMjQxYzIi.XNm9Lg.kdZyKkjrhqa2iTnTdtuyXHAylqE&username=test&email=test%40gmail.com&password=test&password2=test&submit=Register
```

app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

from app import routes, models
```

app/forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, ValidationError, Email, EqualTo
from app.models import User

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField('Repeate Password',
                              validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError("Please use a different username!")

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError("Please use a different email!")
```

app/models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from app import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from app import login

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref="author", lazy="dynamic")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
        print("user password is set!")

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body)


@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

app/routes.py

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse
from app import app, db
from app.forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm
from app.models import User


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    posts = [
        {
            'author': {'username': 'John'},
            'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland!'
        },
        {
            'author': {'username': 'Susan'},
            'body': 'The Avengers movie was so cool!'
        }
    ]
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', posts=posts)


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

How can I resolve this issue and make the registration work? Thanks!

Comment: Without the code, we won't be able to diagnose the problem so please add the code to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form action is not acceptable for [HTML5 specification](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-action). It must:

> ...have a value that is a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces.

So, in your form HTML, remove `action`.

Comment: Thanks @dylanj.nz. This fixed the issue. But how do you know there is an `action` in my HTML? I didn't share the html file, or did I?

Comment: I clicked the link and inspected the HTML. It would be helpful in future if you include all necessary code in questions, however!